# I'm weirdly not able to install pygame in conda environment for game development in Python

Tags: python, pygame, anaconda, conda

I'm learning Python and have switched to Anaconda for it provides much more support and pre-installed libraries than the normal version. Just as I begin to start with pygame, I've this error in Anaconda Prompt trying to install it:

```
conda install pygame
Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): done
Solving environment: failed with initial frozen solve. Retrying with flexible solve.
Collecting package metadata (repodata.json): done
Solving environment: failed with initial frozen solve. Retrying with flexible solve.

PackagesNotFoundError: The following packages are not available from current channels:

  - pygame

Current channels:

  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/win-64
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/noarch
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/win-64
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/noarch
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/msys2/win-64
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/msys2/noarch

To search for alternate channels that may provide the conda package you're
looking for, navigate to

    https://anaconda.org

and use the search bar at the top of the page.
```

Please help me to access pygame as my friends have no problem in working with it, and I tried re-installing, but even that doesn't helps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you follow the suggestion in the error message and got to anaconda.org and enter `pygame`, then you find that it is not available from the default channel. The only option, if you want to install using `conda`, would be to use one of the channels from which it is available, e.g. `CogSci`. So to create an environment for your game development, you could for example do:

```
conda create -n pygame -c CogSci pygame
```

or, if you want to install to an existing environment (note that having a seperate environment for seperate projects is advisbale), then you can install pygame with

```
conda install -c CogSci pygame
```

Note though that the version in that channel is over 5 years old. An alternative is that you could install pygame using pip:#

```
pip install pygame
```

Comment: When I look up "CogSci pygame" I find this: https://anaconda.org/cogsci/pygame, which shows that the pygame on this channel is nearly 6 years out of date, an ancient pygame version. I don't use conda but I've heard that you can use pip installed packages with it, that may be a better solution if it works.

Comment: Good comment, I overlooked the version. You are correct that you can just use pip to install into a conda env. I will add it into the answer